# Is there a way I can ensure that all stored properties are initialized in a class when it inherits from a class that is initialized after it?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

First I make a class for initializing some object that can be tapped

```
class ObjectNode: SKSpriteNode {
let onTap: () -> ()
let objectManager: ObjectManager

init(onTap: @escaping () -> (), pos: CGPoint, objectManager: ObjectManager) {
    self.onTap = onTap
    self.objectManager = objectManager
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "objectImage")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
    
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    self.position = pos
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if objectManager.objectTouched {
        return
    }
    onTap()
}}
```

Then I make a container class to draw all my tappable objects onto the screen

```
class Object: SKNode {
let object1: ObjectNode
let objectMenu: ObjectMenu
let pos: CGPoint
init(size: CGSize, objectTapped: @escaping () -> (), objectManager: ObjectManager, objectMenu: ObjectMenu) {
    self.objectMenu = objectMenu
    pos = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    object1 = ObjectNode(onTap: objectTapped, pos: pos, objectManager: objectManager)
    addChild(object1)
    super.init()
}}
```

When the object is tapped it opens a menu containing another tappable object

```
class ObjectMenu: SKNode {
let menuImage: SKSpriteNode
let menuNode: ObjectNode
let objectManager: ObjectManager
init(size: CGSize, objectManager: ObjectManager) {
    self.objectManager = objectManager
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "menuImage")
    menuImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
    menuImage.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    menuNode = ObjectNode(onTap: objectManager.objectAction, pos: menuImage.position, objectManager: objectManager)
    super.init()
}

func objectTapped() {
    addChild(menuImage)
    objectManager.objectTouched = true
}}
```

And finally I have one last class to manage the functions of the menu objects, and one of the functions is adding more of the objects from the first class I mentioned into the scene.

```
class ObjectManager: Object {
var objectTouched = false

func objectAction() {
    let object2 = ObjectNode(onTap: objectMenu.objectTapped, pos: pos, objectManager: objectMenu.objectManager)
    addChild(object2)
}}
```

So the problem I run into is how to initialize each class when they rely on strong references to eachother's properties. One way or another some property that is needed for something in one class isn't initialized until after the class that needs it is initialized. One idea I considered trying was to make the properties optional but I'm not clear on how to pass the void functions to the parameters as optionals or how to safely unwrap them.

All of the classes are initialized during the GameScene class's initializer, in the following order: ObjectManager, ObjectMenu, Object.

Comment: It seems like you have some circular dependencies here: `ObjectManager` (which inherits from `Object`) has an `ObjectMenu` property, but `ObjectMenu` also has an `ObjectManager` property. I would recommend looking for a way to separate the responsibilities of each of these classes so that dependencies only flow in one direction (either `ObjectMenu` depends on `ObjectManager` or vice versa, not both)

Comment: would you mind suggesting how you would structure this hierarchy? Maybe I should get rid of the objectManager class altogether?